# Array's values auto define as needed

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

i need to define the array values as need. Here i say that the value will be **0 to 2.** But i need someway to say the value can be null and also it can be **0 to 1000.**

```
$apartment = array(
                0,
                1,
                2
            );

foreach ($apartment AS $apt) {

                $userApt = $area->getApartments()->get($apt)->getApartment();
                echo $userApt . "<br>";
}
```

**Please note that the value can be 0 and it should stop where there is no available value ...**

**i mean if get(0) is available it should get the value, if get(1) is not available it should stop there and do nothing , so the main purpose is to get the value where it is available, when it is not available, do nothing...**

Comment: So what's preventing you from building your array as such?

Comment: i just do not know how to build that array

Comment: What do you mean by "*it should stop where there is no available value*". What is *it*? What do you mean by *stop*? *Stop* what?

Comment: i mean $userApt = $area->getApartments()->get(0)->getApartment(); ......if it is available it should take the value if not than do nothing , so the main purpuse is to get the value where it is availabe, when it is not available, do nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your lasts edits, there is no need to build such an array. You can get your objects directly within the loop.

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i <= 1000; ++$i) {
    $userApt = $area->getApartments()->get($i);
    if(!$userApt) {
        break;
    } else {
        var_dump($userApt->getApartment());
    }
}
```

This would stop as soon as an object cannot be retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need something where it stop looping if there is no available data , i mean if get(0) is avalable it should get the value, if get(1) is not available it should stop there ...

Comment: @ChristoferHansen: Just edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your good answer, but the problem is ---- where the value is not available it returns an error like so ---Error: Call to a member function getApartment() on a non-object,  it returns like ---Array ( [0] => myhello.com ) Array ( [0] => myhello.com [1] => myhello.com_mobile ) Array ( [0] => myhello.com [1] => myhello.com_mobile [2] => hello.com ) .... than the error message

Comment: What the `get()` method returns in case of it fails retrieving the object? `false`? `null`?

Comment: i am working on someone else code but i guess it will be "false"

Comment: So this code shouldn't raise the error as the loop breaks when `$userApt` is `false` (or equivalent). Are you sure you're using it properly?

Comment: i am sure i am using it properly, but i am guessing get() method is set to something so when it null or false it return this error ... it's really starnge